# How To Loop Over Array Of Objects And Rewrite A Property Value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a Features array that contains objects. The featureUrl is returned from a service which it gathers from a database. All works great in my desktop angular app that uses ngRoute. But, I'm building an Ionic mobile app that uses UIRouter which seems to have caused an issue. I cannot build a url like below as they all output 'index.html#/app/my-account' from the state provider.

Ionic Code Abbrv

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

.state('app', {
url: '/app',
abstract: true,
templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
controller: 'AppCtrl'
})

.state('app.my-account', {
url: '/my-account',
views: {
  'menuContent': {
    templateUrl: 'templates/my-account.html',
    controller: 'accountController'
  }
}
})
```

So, my question is, in my Ionic app, is it possible to build URLs directly off of the trailing slash? (ie. index.html#/my-account) so they match my Svc object, or will they always be appended behind 'app' like index.html#/app/my-account?

If not, could someone help me with looping over my object and splitting the Url string and inserting the /app/ into the url so my data will work for UIRouter?

```
Features
[{
featureClass: 'hasStuff',
featureUrl: 'index.html#/my-account',
featureBlah: 'blah'
},
{
featureClass: 'hasCoolStuff',
featureUrl: 'index.html#/my-profile',
featureBlah: 'blah' 
},
{
featureClass: 'hasMoreCoolStuff',
featureUrl: 'index.html#/motorcycles',
featureBlah: 'blah'
}]
```

Here's what I'm thinking when it comes to rewriting the featureUrl string, but getting stuck.

```
var featureUrlRewrite = function () {
  var index;
  var alteredUrl;
for (index = 0, index < $scope.Features.length, index++) {
   alteredUrl = $scope.featureUrl[index];
   featureUrl = alteredUrl.split("/").append("app/")
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It may work if you use regex to add "/app" behind the # symbol:

```
for(var index=0, index<$scope.Features.length(); index++){
   $scope.Features[index]['featureUrl'] = $scope.Features[index]['featureUrl'].replace("(.*#)(.*)", "$1/app$2"); 
}
```

That should capture everything before and including the # symbol as well as everything after it as a separate capture and insert /app between the two parts of the string.

I am not familiar with ngRoute or what platform you are working on, but hopefully that helps out!

Comment: `replace` does not modify the original...it returns a new string

Comment: Just noticed that I need to add a comment to notify a user of changes... does the above resolve your issue?